# Effect of using Cholesky transpose

Tags: covariance-matrix, cholesky-decomposition

I am generating random normal samples ***Y*** with covariance ***C*** using a well known procedure:

1. Let ***L*** be the Cholesky decomposition of ***C***, such that $C = LL^T$.
2. Now given a matrix of random numbers $X, x_{ij} \sim N(0,1)$, compute $Y = XL$.
3. We expect $\mathrm{var}[Y] \approx C$.

Except that in testing this I am finding that this appears to be true only if I compute $Y = XL^T$.

I am looking for an explanation of which of the Cholesky transposes should be used and why that one works and the other doesn't.  Or what the other transpose is producing if not a matrix ***Y*** with covariance approximating ***C***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from
$$\mathrm{var}[AX]=A\mathrm{var}[X]A^T$$
and $\mathrm{var}[X]=I$

So
$$\mathrm{var}[LX]=L\mathrm{var}[X]L^T=LL^T=C$$
and
$$\mathrm{var}[L^TX]=L^T\mathrm{var}[X]L=L^TL\neq C$$

So, the formula is correct and you should perhaps post what  you actually did and the result you get

There are two computational complications that you need to work around

- if $C$ is $p\times p$, then so is $L$. If you want to multiply $X$ on the right by $L$ to generate $n$ rows of data, $X$ has to be $p\times n$, and $LX$ will also be $p\times n$, but you want $\mathrm{var}[LX]$ to be $p\times p$. You'll need a transpose somewhere
- some software (such as `chol` in R) will give you the right-triangular Cholesky transpose $R=L^T$

Modulo those issues, it works for me

```
> C
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    2    3    2
[3,]    2    2    3
> chol(C)
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.732051 1.154701 1.1547005
[2,] 0.000000 1.290994 0.5163978
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 1.1832160
> (L<-t(chol(C)))
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 1.732051 0.0000000 0.000000
[2,] 1.154701 1.2909944 0.000000
[3,] 1.154701 0.5163978 1.183216
> X<-matrix(rnorm(3*1000),ncol=3)
> var(X%*%L)
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 5.676307 2.0722716 1.3934165
[2,] 2.072272 1.9764387 0.6193953
[3,] 1.393416 0.6193953 1.3481810
> var(X%*%t(L))
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 3.029680 1.939776 2.037781
[2,] 1.939776 2.932426 2.013214
[3,] 2.037781 2.013214 3.014312
```

So, $\mathrm{var}[XL^T]=C$ as you'd expect, and $\mathrm{var}[XL]\neq C$, also as you'd expect

Comment: You're saying my result is correct, and that my description of the procedure contains the error?  I.e., if $C = LL^T$ then the correct procedure is to compute $Y = XL^T$?

Comment: Your maths is correct. I have no way of telling whether your test is correct, because you didn't say how you did it. Computing $LX$ or $X^TL$ is just a matter of whether $X$ is stored by rows or by columns. On the other hand, $L^TX$ or $XL$ (whichever one has the right dimensions) would give the wrong answer.